# Error de conexión de jdb con mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public static Connection getConexion(){
    String url = "jdb:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
            + "database=Escuela;"
            + "user=ANDREASUSUSUARIO;"
            + "password= ;";
    
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }
}
```

No puedo conectarme con MySQL, el Netbeans no importa el `java.sql.Connection`, si no otro que es el `com.sun.connect.spi.Connection.`
Lo tuve que importar manualmente al `java.sql`, pero cuando hago un objeto de Connection, como está en el try, me sale error, como si no hubiera importado nada. Ayuda comunidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. ¿Cuál es el error? por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/558159/edit) tu pregunta y añádenos ese detalle.

Comment: No reconoce Netbeans el SQL, obviamente ya agregué el JAR, y probé con muchos, pero no reconoce, tengo que importarlo manualmente, pero cuando hago una instancia del mismo, me sale error, como que no exista el import que hice.

Comment: Por favor, pon el mensaje de error. No lo resumas, no lo traduzcas. Ve a [edit] y pon el error que sale. Completo.

Comment: no es **jdbc** ? dale una revisada [como crear la direccion de  url](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ya intentaste con un try con recursos?

Comment: En si no es un error como tal, si no me sale que tengo que crear una clase nueva para la instancia DriveManager, este mismo está en el paquete de sql, pero no lo reconoce. Será un bug?

Comment: *me sale error*... a que te refieres con eso?

Comment: En el DriveManager, me sale subrayado de color rojo(error), y en el foco me sale que debo crear una clase de este en el programa(no debería salir eso, ya que está incluido en el paquete de sql), si me entiendes ahora?

Comment: Bueno, parece que tuve que importar la libreria de DriveManager, y importe las demas para evitar errores futuros